# How can i calculate the direction vector of a pixel?

Tags: focal-length, optics, image-processing, calculations

So if you take a pinhole camera and make it as the origin of our plane(3D) and a pixel from the image plane and connect the two with a straight line it should make a vector, which has direction and a length. Think of this as the path followed by the light reflected from an object into the camera lens. And i want to calculate this. I think we have to use the cameras intrinsic properties for this.

Below is a statement that made me think about it all.

> In a pinhole camera model, each pixel defines a direction vector in 3D space, specifically the vector from the projection center through the pixel's position on the image plane.

Below is an image better explaining this. I want to calculate the three red lines, and known parameters would be, i guess, the camera position(origin) and the image pixel value, and the intrinsic camera parameters.

[image]

Comment: Where oh where did you get that image?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view). If you know the focal length and the pixel position from the center (pixel coordinates factored by sensor pixel density), you know the angle of the view ray.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math/engineering question.

Comment: @Hueco i googled ray tracing and in the images tab....i found it after a couple scrolls. I had seen a similar image thought i could find it but this worked too... https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Ray_trace_diagram.svg/300px-Ray_trace_diagram.svg.png

Comment: Gotcha. I just found it interesting because it shows the camera shooting an image out in front of a camera...which is just odd. The captured image is behind the lens.

Comment: @Hueco The OPs image seems to be representation of a 3D image render.  You have the 3D scene objects in front of the plane.  The camera object represents the location, aspect ratio and field of view of the observer and the image represents the plane (monitor screen) onto where the 2D image of the 3D scene is projected.  The use of "camera" in this case is a standard in 3D graphics.

Comment: @xenoid yes i feel that now, before i thought it was more to do with the focal length and all part and i had seen similar problems being solved here so asked.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, your illustration shows the image in the wrong place. The image is formed behind the lens. Moreover, the image is doubly inverted with regard to the actual object:

[image: Object imaged by pinhole]

If you put the pinhole at the origin (0, 0, 0), things are quite simple: no calculations are necessary, just a reflection about the origin. Suppose the film/sensor plane is a distance *f* away from the pinhole. A point (*x*, *y*) in the plane then corresponds to the vector (*x*, *y*, –*f*). Invert this and you get (–*x*, –*y*, *f*) pointing in the direction of the object. Multiply by the distance to the object, and I think you have the vector you were asking about.

Comment: If the OPs illustration is of a 3D render (which it seems to be) then the image is shown in the correct location.

Comment: @PeterM i dont quit get what you mean but [link](http://doc-ok.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/SphereCone.png) might help get a better idea.

Comment: @Kahovius i have the same basics in mind...but since i have the point (x,y) in pixels from the image and the real object is f _meters_ away, how am i to deal with this. btw f here is unknown.

Comment: @rockangator Your original illustration portrays how a 3D scene (EG from a game engine) is rendered onto a 2D plane (EG a monitor).  In the 3D rendering world a "camera" is the term used to describe the orientation and location of the person viewing the scene (EG the "center of projection" as per that link)